# If class doesn't exist do this else ignore

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement, contains

Hi what I'm trying to do in Javascript is to find if a class '.promo' exists in the '.productDetails' div, if it does then no action needs to be taken, but if it doesn't exist then i want it to print the copy in the span tags. I know this can be done in jQuery but looking to do this in plain Javascript instead.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.product-details');
if(!elem.classlist.contains('.promo')){
   document.querySelector('.title').innerHTML += "<span class="promo">Add Promo Banner</span>";
 }
```

```css
.product-details {border: 1px black solid; margin: 10px 0}
```

```html
<div class="product-details">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="promo">Promo 20% off</div>
</div>

<div class="product-details">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As the [documentation for `.classlist` shows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) you have to pass the actual class name and not a class selector to `.contains()`

Comment: Firstly, it's `classList`. Second, your string has unescapted quotes. Third, don't *ever* use `.innerHTML +=` - use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead. Fourth, you're testing if the `.product-details` element itself has the `.promo` class; to test if the element contains a `.promo` child, use `.querySelector('.promo')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, case matters in JS (`classlist` != `classList`), should be camel case `classList`. ALso, the *htmlString* (`"<span class="promo">Add Promo Banner</span>"`) is not properly formatted.

You can check the *length* by getting element with `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.product-details');
elem.forEach(function(el){
  if(!el.querySelectorAll('.promo').length){
    el.querySelector('.title').innerHTML += "<span class=promo>Add Promo Banner</span>";
  }
});
```

```css
.product-details {border: 1px black solid; margin: 10px 0}
```

```html
<div class="product-details">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="promo">Promo 20% off</div>
</div>

<div class="product-details">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this but the span tag with the copy "Add Promo banner" should get added under the second title as the .promo class doesn't exist there.

Comment: @leek1234, in that case, you have to loop through all the items and check the condition for each. I have updated the answer. Please check:)

Comment: sorry one last question, if i wanted to find if the .promo class exists or the class .text how would i do this? The idea would be the same, not to print the span tag with teh copy.

Comment: @leek1234, in that case you can add another condition `if(!el.querySelectorAll('.promo').length || !el.querySelectorAll('.text').length){`

Comment: Thanks @Mamun i've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. The span tag prints on both now.

Comment: Got this working now, I've done this and it's worked
      if(!el.querySelectorAll('.promo, .text').length)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the JS, the issue in your code is just the syntax. The member is called

`<HTML element>.classList`

You're just missing the capitalized L.

`elem.classList` will not return `".classNameA .classNameB"`, but rather the actual string value of the class attribute, like this: `"classNameA classNameB"`

But still, I do not believe that your code will behave properly if you make these changes, because you are searching an element for a class that it does not inherit from. The element that inherits from `"promo"` is a child element of the element you have a reference to.

The element you are looking for in your particular code is found in the `elem.children` array, which is iterable.

Are you trying to search all children of all elements on the page to find heirs of `.classList` containing `"promo"`? If so, you should check out tree traversal algorithms! The more obvious implementations of this are that you would start at some root and navigate down via depth-first or breadth-first searching. The DOM is really just a giant tree of elements.